# UNIX C Shell Scripting. Copying files and adding extension

Tags: unix

I'm trying to write a script that copies files from one directory to another and adds a .bak extension to them. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add the extension.

```
foreach file in ($argv[1]/*)
    cp $file $argv[2]
end
```

Comment: The first rule of C shell scripting is 'Use a different shell — `bash` or `ksh` or plain `sh`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a bunch of assumptions (mainly that the outline of your script is valid C shell syntax, and that spaces in file names are not an issue), then you probably need to use the `basename` command:

```
foreach file in ($argv[1]/*)
    cp $file $argv[2]/`basename $file`.bak
end
```

The `basename` command removes the pathname, so the files will be copied precisely to the directory named by `$argv[2]`.  If you're looking to retain directory hierarchies too, you have to work a fair bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

$1 and $2 are the arguments (directories) to the script-:

```
for f in $1/*
do
    fname=$(basename $f)
    cp $f $2/$fname.bak
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working. echo $f --> directory/filename. So when I try to type that in it causes an error.

Comment: are you using absolute or relative paths for $1 and $2?

Comment: relative paths. The problem is with the $f variable containing not only its filename, but also it's relative directory.

Comment: How does `cp $fidr/$fname ...` differ from `cp $f ...` in practice?  I agree with the second argument to `cp`, but...the first can be simpler.

Comment: Yes agreed - `cp $f $2/$fname.bak` is best.